# Mapping out JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I'm parsing a JSON message which looks something like:

```
{ 
    staff : [
       {name : 'John', department : 'Math'},
       {name : 'Sally', department : 'Science'},
    ],
    students : [
       {name : 'Bob', department : 'Law'},
       {name : 'Lisa', department : 'IT'}
    ]
}
```

From which I'd like to pull out an array of each separate value.
i.e.

```
names -> ['John', 'Sally', 'Bob', 'Lisa']
```

At the moment I'm doing something like

```
var names = [];
msg.staff.forEach(function(e) { names.push(e.name) })
msg.students.forEach(function(e) { names.push(e.name)})
```

This feels overly verbose, just wondering if there's a cleaner way to approach this (for every attribute). I'm already including lodash in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_.pluck` to get the value of a property of each object in an array:

```
_.pluck(obj.staff.concat(obj.students), 'name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is right; you don't need a mutable array to do this with lodash.

```
_(obj).map().flatten().pluck('name').value();
```

This version works for any number of array values in `o`.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hiqosa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: This is the same approach I would take. Except I'd use `values()` in place of `map()`. It's a little clearer what's happening, and actually does less work internally than `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** missed that you had lodash available, will leave this vanilla JS version here anyway.

You could use map to be more concise:

```
var directory = { 
    staff : [
       {name : 'John', department : 'Math'},
       {name : 'Sally', department : 'Science'},
    ],
    students : [
       {name : 'Bob', department : 'Law'},
       {name : 'Lisa', department : 'IT'}
    ]
};

var names = directory.staff.concat(directory.students).map(function(person) {
   return person.name;
});
```

If you don't know the individual key names before hand, you could do:

```
Object.keys(directory).map(function(key) { 
  return directory[key] 
}).reduce(function(p,c){ 
  return p.concat(c) 
}).map(function(person) {
   return person.name;
});
```

I didn't catch the requirement of getting an array of all values stored under each key, this should do it though:

```
Object.keys(directory).map(function(key) { 
  return directory[key];
}).reduce(function(p,c) { 
  return p.concat(c);
}).reduce(function(p, c) {
   Object.keys(c).forEach(function(oKey) {
     if(p[oKey]) p[oKey].push(c[oKey]);
     else p[oKey] = [c[oKey]];
   });
   return p;
}, {});
```

This returns the following:

```
{
  "name":["John","Sally","Bob","Lisa"],
  "department": ["Math","Science","Law","IT"]
}
```

Comment: This would mean I'd have to loop the array for each attribute though. I should have made it clearer in the question.

Comment: I meant each attribute of the lowest node, i.e. name, department, etc.